# Trigger in working as expected in inline editing , But it is not not working when I click the edit button

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

Hi Folks I have a requirement to copy the case contact id to the task **(WhoId)** Field.

Logic I implemented.

**1**: Check the task **whatID** is not blank and the **whatId** starts with 500 (*Case Prefix Which gives indication about the task is related to the case*).

```
trigger TaskTrigger on Task(before insert, before update) {

    //determine the prefix for Case sObject
    String casePrefix = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getKeyPrefix();
    if(casePrefix == null){
        casePrefix = '500';
    }
    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id> ();
    for (Task aTask : Trigger.new) {
        if(aTask.WhatId != null){
            if (((String) aTask.WhatId).startsWith(casePrefix)) { caseIds.add(aTask.WhatId); }            
        }
    }
    Map<Id, Case> caseMap = new Map<Id, Case> ([SELECT Id, OwnerID, ContactId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds]);

    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {

        if (t.WhatId != null && ((String) t.WhatId).startsWith(casePrefix) ) {
             System.debug('Execution Check'+t.WhoId);
            t.WhoId = caseMap.get(t.WhatId).ContactId;
            Id currentCaseOwnerId = caseMap.get(t.WhatId).OwnerId;    
            if ((t.Treatment_Profile__c != null || t.Case_Profile__c != null) && string.valueOf(currentCaseOwnerId).startsWith('005')) {
                t.OwnerID = currentCaseOwnerId;
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

I am facing the problem now.

**1:** When I am creating a task the **WhoId** field value is not getting populated.

**2:** When I am editing the task with edit button The **WhoId** field value is not getting populated

**3:** When I am doing inline editing on the task the trigger is working as expected (Copying the value of contact id from case to the task **whoId** field).

Can anyone suggest me why the trigger is not working at creation and while editing ..  (I CHECK THE DEBUG LOG , IN EVERY SCENARIO I AM GETTING THE RESULT FOR `LINE 19 System.debug('Execution Check'+t.WhoId);` )

Really appreciate your prompt reply.

Comment: Are triggeres being fired in all scenarios?

Comment: Also do you have asignment rules? They dont run in inline edit, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BptYAAS

Comment: side note, get rid of all this keyprefix stuff and use the `getSObjectType()` method on the ID class e.g. `t.WhatId.getSObjectType() == Case.SObjectType` - much clearer

Comment: @Pranay Jaiswal . Yes the trigger is fired in all scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce Know issue is in review .
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000Su0FAAS&title=known-issue-with-shared-activities-feature-and-event-triggers

When shared activities is on, task or event triggers that modify whoId or activity relations may not save correctly